# Url to display Sql Server Reporting Services as a PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, reporting-services

I'm trying to get the Sql Server Report Services to downloads reports in PDF so that I can display them in the browser.

```
var uriDownload = new Uri("https://myServer.com/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?
                             ItemPath=item/path&rs:Format=pdf");
var strSavePath = "C:\\myFolder\\testAAA123.pdf";
var wcli = new System.Net.WebClient();
wcli.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
wcli.DownloadFile(uriDownload, strSavePath);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(strSavePath);
```

When I run this code, I Get an error saying that the PDF file cannot be opened. When replace `pdf` with `txt`, I get a text file that contains an aspx code, i.e. with Viewstate, etc. I guess it's because of the url which ends with an aspx.

When I try something like  `https://myServer.com/Reports/Pages/item/path&rs:Format=pdf`, I get `400 - Bad Request`

How should the URL for a request to return report in PDF looks like?

Thank for helping.

Comment: "I guess it's because of the url which ends with an aspx", I think it is because the content of the URL. Are you sure it is returning a PDF file? Can you check that?

Comment: @Transcendent, I'm sure it's not returning PDF. As I said in my question, when I change the extension of the text file to HTML, I'm getting the version I'm looking at. I don't want the HTML version. I want the PDF one. Do I need to configure something or just by the rigth url, I'll be able to get a PDF version.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: The report server is 2014

Comment: According to Microsoft the URL export format for 2014 is `http://myrshost/ReportServer?/myreport&rs:Format=PDF`. I have not done this before, can you try to make the `pdf` uppercase as `PDF` and check the result?

Comment: I guess myrhost is supposed to `myCompany.com`. Is `myrepors` a folder or a path?

Comment: You may get the error 400 when you do not supply report parameters in your URL. Does your report need any?